# Connect MS access database in JSP pages

Tags: database, jsp, ms-access-2007

I would like to ask you how can I connect a MS access database in JSP pages?Do you know any ready class which I can use?I am using Netbeans to create JSP pages!

Comment: Oracle JVM comes with the JdbcOdbcDriver jdbc driver that you can use to open the MS Access database over ODBC.

Answer (score 2):

Ancient question, but I shall answer anyway. Had to Google around a bit when the same question flummoxed me. Here goes (concise version of stuff found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEcQFjAD&url=http://cs.njit.edu/mchugh/psswrd/web-course-materials/IT202/Fall-03-Lectures/AccessDBs/DataBases-JSP-Topics.doc&ei=EqCPUYqwFMP3rQfHmIHQAQ&usg=AFQjCNGTae9eUBNtClOt-JZunBaNb4BjMw&sig2=8niDVpyRcEVcDkukSAjVuA&bvm=bv.46340616,d.bmk)):

**Administratively Register Database**

1. Use MS Access to create a blank database in some directory.   (eg. `Database1.mdb`.)   Make sure to close the data base after it is created.
2. Go to: Control panel -> Admin tool -> ODBC
3. Under the System DSN tab (for Tomcat version 5 or later – User DSN for earlier 
           versions), un-highlight any previously selected name and then click on the Add 
           button.
4. On the window that then opens up, highlight MS Access Driver & click Finish.
5. On the ODBC Setup window that then opens, fill in the data source name.  This 
       is the name that you will use to refer to the data base in your Java program – like
       `arc`.  This name does not have to match the file name.
   .
6. Then click Select and navigate to the already created database in directory.
      Suppose the file name is `Database1.mdb`. After highlighting the named file,
      click OKs all the way back to the original window.

**Connect a JSP page to an Access Database**

```
 <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

    <%
            Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");             
            Connection  conn=null;  
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:arc", "", "");  
    out.println ("Database Connected.");
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8, the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver may be a more relevant option for future users. For details, see the related Stack Overflow question

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)